# how to represent a composite primary key in ER

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I have an entity (building) that use (B_id) as its primary key, and I have another entity (office) that have an (Office_Number) as its first primary key, the second primary key should be (B_id) a Foreign key from the entity (building), that means (Office_Number) and ((B_id) Foreign key from building) will be a composite primary key for the entity (office).
the problem is I don't know if I should represent composite key in the ER.

Comment: Is Office_Number truly a primary key? If so, there's no need to specify that Office_Number and B_id make up a composite key, since the primary key and any other combination of columns included will still be unique. That being said, you can't have a "second primary key." There can only be one primary key in a table.

Comment: office number can be duplicated, the same office number could be in multiple buildings but not in the same building